# Servlets calls method from Service via DAO in Java with MongoDB POJOs for CRUD operation

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets

I am following this [POJO's example](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/) to output a list of users with the `Object id` but show nothing in the list. I'm not sure if the connection is correct with the `CodecRegistry` or something wrong in one of my below classes. Tried to use the Eclipse debugger but got no hints with that.

Firstmost the connection

```
ConnectionString connectiontring = new ConnectionString(
                    "my connection to database");
            MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)                     
                    .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder -> builder.maxWaitTime(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .applyConnectionString(connectiontring).retryWrites(false).build();

            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);

            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DATABASE");
```

Here is my list user method in DAO class

```
    @Override
    public List<User> listAll() {

        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        // 1. get the table from dB
        MongoCollection<Document> userTbl = database.getCollection("User");

        // loop through the table to find, then add
        for (Document doc : userTbl.find()) {
            User user = new User((String) doc.get("fullname"), (String) doc.get("email"), (String) doc.get("password"));

    userList.add(user);
}

return userList;
```

}

Service class just call the method from DAO class

```
    public List<User> listUser() {

        List<User> userList = userDAO.listAll();        
        
        return userList;

    }
```

The Controller

```
public class ListUsersServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public ListUsersServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        UserService userService = new UserService(request, response);

        List<User> userList = userService.listUser();

        String list_user_page = "user_list.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(list_user_page);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding something into the user list. It should work.

Comment: It's hard to understand what happens here. You should at least provide line numbers for files if you reference them.

Comment: @AndreiKovrovy the service class has only that few lines to call the method from DAO class. Do you mean put a line number next to that syntax where the NPE occurred? My apology as I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: As long as you can't ask "Why is variable X null?" while pointing out the exact variable X in a normal [mcve], but you can only ask "Why do I get a NullPointerException?", then the abovelinked duplicate totally answers your real question.

Comment: My apology, will try follow the standard to ask again differently.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you have NPE in the UserService.listUser() method. Maybe UserDAO is null. May you check it?